# Checking the uniqueness of a new journal's name

Tags: journals, publishers

I am part of a group that wants to publish a new journal in the field of economic sciences. I am coming up with the journal name and will then register a domain in that name. But I have to be sure about distinctiveness of the name.
How can I check that the journal name has not been used by others earlier? Is there another method except googling?

Comment: Why do you want to publish a new journal? What's wrong with the existing journals in this field? (Also see: [How is a new academic journal born?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8708/how-is-a-new-academic-journal-born), [Steps for creating a scientific journal](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36570/steps-for-creating-a-scientific-journal), and [How do I start a new peer-reviewed open access journal?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/67490/11365), [How to create an editorial board for a new journal](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/62670/11365))

Comment: I think average response time of high ranked journals to authors is very high. Then it is very important case. Our editorial board is ready and I am entrusted to fşnd a proper name for the journal.

Comment: So, why do you think your journal would be any better: do you know, and have you accounted for, the reasons for high-level journals taking longer to respond? Is what "you think" even objectively measured or correct?

Comment: JCR should tell you whether there is a journal with proper IF that has the same name.

Comment: I think new journals in the economic sciences is needed. Because the queue time for review is very very long. For example I sent an article to a the middle ranked journal and they informed me that the process of reviewing will be start eight month later.

Comment: @Huseyin: eight month before the reviewing *starts*? Whao, I thought in maths we were the slowest publishing field, no I know I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly checked whether it is registered (unless it is registered only in some obscure country), but I don't have fine knowledge of where to look. However, a search on the keywords "brand registration record journal" led me to http://www.wipo.int/branddb/en/ where you can do a check through several databases.

Note that some journal use a name without having registered its name, and would thus not appear. I am not sure if it makes it ok to use that name even on a legal basis (it may not be on a practical basis: *The Annals of Mathematics* are not to be found there, but naming a new journal that way would be at best ridiculous).

In conclusion, if you want to be safe on the legal side it would probably be the job of a lawyer to advise you.

Answer (score 1):

Consult scholar databases such as Scopus, Web of Science / Journal Citation Report, Scimago...

(This in addition to googling, of course, not instead of it.)

If it's neither on Google nor on these databases, it's effectively like it has never existed.

Another thing that you may want to check is that there is no journal with the exact same name but in another language. For instance, you don't want to end up with a journal called "Annals of Mathematics" and another one called "Mathematische Annalen"; that's just unnecessarily confusing for German speakers, right?

Comment: If either of those journals had been newer, I would have suspected that the newest one was named in order to score free credit from the existence of the other (as seems to be a common strategy of predatory journals nowadays). But of course, those are both old and well-respected journals.

Comment: Scopus, Scimago ... contain only high ranked journals and other journals were not listed there.

Comment: I would recommend checking Beale's list also, to make sure there's no predatory journal you might be confused with either.